# CSS Table Display Mixture of Fixed and Dynamic Widths

Tags: html, css

Sorry about the title, I couldn't really think of a way to explain this in a single line.

I am attempting to lay out a "table" with three "cells" in a "column" (quotes are because I want to use CSS to lay this out, not a table). The center cell contains an image, which I want to be centered on, and I want the "cells" on either side of the image to be equal in width.

I am using this as my CSS:

```css
.psuedo-table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.psuedo-table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.psuedo-table-column {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

In my HTML, I have the following:

```html
<div class="psuedo-table">
   <div class="psuedo-table-row">
      <div class="psuedo-table-column" style="background-color: #446078;">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="psuedo-table-column" style="max-width: 100%; white-space: nowrap;">
         <img src="/assets/images/appheader.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="psuedo-table-column" style="background-color: #162a52;">&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, as the three "cells" are the same width, and I need the middle "cell" to expand to the width of the `<img>` and the cells on the left and right to be equal width.

This is probably simple, but if anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are the first and last column empty? Or will there be content in them?

Comment: For now they will be empty, except for a ```&nbsp;```. However, I will need to set a background color on the "empty" columns, so I do need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). See the snippet below.

```css
.psuedo-table-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.psuedo-table-column:nth-child(1),
.psuedo-table-column:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="psuedo-table">
  <div class="psuedo-table-row">
    <div class="psuedo-table-column" style="background-color: #446078;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="psuedo-table-column">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Giraffe_Mikumi_National_Park.jpg/800px-Giraffe_Mikumi_National_Park.jpg" width="300" />
    </div>
    <div class="psuedo-table-column" style="background-color: #162a52;">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, that mostly worked, but the flex containers on either side of the image did not stretch to the same height as the container with the image in it. Is there a simple fix for that?

Comment: Looks like ```align-self: stretch``` did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CSS flex is an amazing solution for that:

```css
.psuedo-table {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.psuedo-table > div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.psuedo-table > div.image {
  flex: 0 1 80%;
}

.psuedo-table > div:first-child {
  background-color: #446078;
}
.psuedo-table > div:last-child {
  background-color: #162a52;
}
```

```html
<div class="psuedo-table">
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="image">
    image
  </div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```